# Permission dialog is not showing for the INTERNET permission using Dexter Library in android

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

this is the code that i wrote to check the permissions. but the internet permission is always granted, and the dialog only asks for location permission.

```
import android.Manifest
import com.karumi.dexter.Dexter
import com.karumi.dexter.PermissionToken
import com.karumi.dexter.listener.PermissionDeniedResponse
import com.karumi.dexter.listener.PermissionGrantedResponse
import com.karumi.dexter.listener.PermissionRequest
import com.karumi.dexter.listener.single.PermissionListener
```

---

```
Dexter.withContext(this)
        .withPermissions(
            Manifest.permission.INTERNET,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
        )
        .withListener(object : MultiplePermissionsListener {
            override fun onPermissionsChecked(p0: MultiplePermissionsReport?) {
                p0?.let {
                    if (p0.areAllPermissionsGranted()) {

                        getWeather()
                        getForecast()

                    }
                }
            }

            override fun onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(
                p0: MutableList<PermissionRequest>?,
                p1: PermissionToken?
            ) {
                p1?.continuePermissionRequest()

            }

        }).check()
```

and these are the permissions that I have added to the **Manifest** file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Comment: Internet permission doesn't  require dialog, because it is not dangerous permission.

Comment: Sensitive permission need to be granted runtime by showing dialog.

Comment: For more info: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview#normal-dangerous

Comment: how can i recall the permission after it is denied by the user for the first time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to request runtime permissions for `dangerous` permissions.

For example, if you look at [the documentation for `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission?hl=en#ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION), you will see that it has:

> Protection level: dangerous

So you need to request that permission at runtime, in addition to having a manifest `<uses-permission>` element for it.

Conversely, [the documentation for `INTERNET`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission?hl=en#INTERNET) has:

> Protection level: normal

You do not need to request that permission at runtime, and trying to do so will not work.

Comment: how can i recall the permission after it is denied by the user for the first time?

Comment: @MohsenMashkour: The user should not have been able to deny the `INTERNET` permission, so I do not understand your question, sorry!

Comment: forget about the internet permission. I'm talking about the location permission.

Comment: I'm testing the app and when I'm denied permission it appears only once after that and it won't appear anymore.

Comment: @MohsenMashkour: I do not use Dexter, sorry!

Comment: what is your recommendation? what should i use instead of the Dexter?

Comment: @MohsenMashkour: Personally, I just use the platform APIs for requesting permissions. Most likely, there is nothing wrong with Dexter -- I just cannot comment on how it works.